# How to remove UIAlertAction from UIAlertController in Swift?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I know you can disable UIAlertAction buttons in a UIAlertController, but is it possible to remove the button completely once it has been added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to remove actions from a `UIAlertController` once added.

The `actions` property can return an array of the added actions, but is a `get` only and can not be set.

Actions are added with the `addAction(_:)` method, but there is not a corresponding `removeAction(_:)` method.

And ultimately, it doesn't really necessarily make a lot of sense to be removing actions from an alert controller once added.  You generally should be reusing the alert controller object once instantiated, so the solution is to simply only added the appropriate actions in the first place.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to want to remove actions from an alert controller once added. It has nothing to do with re-use. It has to do with presenting a concise interface. For example, if you are presenting an alert controller which is used to select a photo for a user's avatar, one may want to add several sources for the photo, and also provide an action to remove the current photo completely *if it is already set*. Sure, you can disable the remove action, but since it isn't always an option, why present it to the user in the first place?

Comment: I'm having exactly the situation that @cue8chalk is describing. It is quite frustrating having to create a new UIAlertController each time I want to have the "Clear Photo" action removed...

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't remove actions there is an easy "dirty" way. Creating a new alert:

```
// Objective-C
UIAlertController *replacingNewAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:yourOldAlert.title message:yourOldAlert.message preferredStyle:yourOldAlert.preferredStyle];
NSMutableArray* mutableActions = yourOldAlert.actions.mutableCopy;

// remove any unwanted actions here ...

for (UIAlertAction *action in mutableActions) {
    [replacingNewAlert addAction:action];
}

yourOldAlert = replacingNewAlert;
```

Of course the best way is to not add the action you want to remove in the first place.

Answer (score -3):

You can instead implement your custom class derived from `UIAlertController` this way and use it instead. You basically defer the setting of actions to the `UIAlertController` and instead capture the action items in your derived class and in `viewDidLoad` set the actions that you have saved to the action `UIAlertController`'s actions.

```
public class MutableUIAlertController : UIAlertController {
    var mutableActions:[UIAlertAction] = []

    override public func addAction(action: UIAlertAction) {
        mutableActions.append(action)
    }

    public func removeAction(action:UIAlertAction) {
        if let index = mutableActions.indexOf(action) {
            mutableActions.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        for action in mutableActions {
            super.addAction(action)
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't subclass UIAlertController. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) say: 

**Important**

**The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**